how to use attach prop to pass child to parent args prop
Basically, boxHelper args are expected to receive object3D and color. I'm aware of attach prop to bind objects to their parents. However, I'm quite confused how to bind the object to the args parent prop.
This is what I have so far:
<boxHelper>
  <mesh attach={"arg"}>
    <boxGeometry args={[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]} />
    <meshBasicMaterial
      color={"red"}
      transparent
      opacity={0.2}
    />
  </mesh>
</boxHelper>

the updated code suggested by Sean Guy.
  <object3D
    quaternion={[0.35, 0.25, 0.13, 0.88]}
    position={[0.343, 0.5238, 0.6338]}
    scale={[3.2707, 1, 1]}
  >
    <mesh>
      <boxGeometry />
      <meshBasicMaterial />

      <Helper
        type={THREE.BoxHelper}
        args={["royalblue"]}
      />
    </mesh>
  </object3D>

Do you know by any change how to make the boxHelper to follow the transformation maken to the mesh object?


there is a new component in Drei as of v9.101.0
https://github.com/pmndrs/drei?tab=readme-ov-file#helper

import { Helper } from '@react-three/drei'
import { BoxHelper } from 'three'

<mesh>
  <boxGeometry />
  <meshBasicMaterial />

  <Helper type={BoxHelper} args={['royalblue']} />
</mesh>


It's true that the box helper got included. However, I'm still facing an issue which is applying the same transformations to the box helper as maken to the mesh object.
